# Range of G-d's educational ways in dealing with disobedience

Tags: theology, chinuch-education

It is a positive Mitzvah to "emulate G-d's ways" (Rambam Deot, 1). To be a better father to my kids, I'm trying to see what educational methods does G-d exercise in the Torah to His sons when they misbehave.

As we can see the Torah testifies that the Jews weren't very obedient, to say the least. And G-d reacted to they misdeeds very promptly. Strangely, it appears to come down to two methods:

1. G-d gets furious and kills his naughty sons immediately or He tells others (Moses, other nations, plagues) to kill them. E.g. the Golden Calf, Aharon's sons, Korach, Mekoshesh, Bnot Moav, Meraglim, etc.

   1.5. G-d gets "less furious" and promises to kill them later - Dor Hamidbar, Moses and Aharon (for Mei Meriva and Golden Calf)
2. G-d overcomes His anger and postpones killing them or pardons them completely (called mercy) - Golden Calf, Kivrot Teavah etc.

What additional methods of dealing with disobedient sons that I missed does G-d demonstrate in the Torah alone?

Comment: I think you're misusing educational. Maybe you mean discipline

Comment: @robev how do you translate "שיטה חינוכית"? The question is מהן השיטות החינוכיות של ה' בתורה? Please help me formulate it.

Comment: Discipline is educational. The emphasis of your question is how to discipline children so they'll know better for next time

Comment: @robev I didn't ask for advices on how to educate kids, only what patterns are offered in the TOrah by G-d to follow.

Comment: God can resurrect those whose lives He takes away, we cannot. God knows both the future and the hearts of men, we do not.

Comment: @Lucian ... and therefore...

Comment: ...and therefore, unless possessing the same specific set of abilities, perhaps one should restrain from *emulating* said methods too closely. (Just a thought).

Comment: Rav Hutner points out that there is no mitzva of *ve'halachta bi'derachav* for the *middas hadin*, only for the *middas ha'rachamim*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE What's the source for that?

Comment: @AlBerko I don't think he gives a source, he seems to take it as obvious, possibly because in the *maamar chazal* of *mah hu rachum af atah rachum* etc., it only quotes *chassadim*. It is probably obvious, otherwise we should say *mah hu kel nekamos, af atah tiheye nokem*, which would be ridiculous.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I've already asked about that cherrypicking Mitzvah - following specific qualities and overlooking others. Why would that be ridiculous?

Comment: @AlBerko See https://www.aish.com/atr/The-Lying-Spirit-Which-Deceived-Ahab.html, "The Talmud (Sanhedrin 89a, 102b) explains that it was the soul of the recently deceased Naboth the Jezreelite." So you see that Navos was allowed and encouraged to take revenge. Rb Mordechai Miller explained that it is true that it would be appropriate for people to take revenge, but it is not possible to do that *lishmah* while we live in this world as fallible people.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the most important ones - training through experience, natural consequences, and guidance.

I agree that we do see examples of Divine discipline, and we also need to learn from that, but that is not what education is built on.

Some examples:

Expelling Adam from Gan Eden - forcing self-development when instuction was not heeded. God does not kill him, but sends him out on his own to learn about life the hard way.

Giving the Torah - instuction, showing intent, and warning of consequences, both natural consequences and discipline.

Forty years in the desert - something between a "time-out" and a guided contemplation, giving lots of time for the old to pass and for new attituted to develop.

See also Rabbis S. R. Hirsch's Nineteen Letters, specifically [Letter 5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nineteen_Letters.5?ven=Bernard_Drachman_translation,_1899&lang=en), which present a educational approach of Judaism on the societal level.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your effort. I'd say your answer is too vague to start a discussion. You also mix Phat and interpretations. G-d sentenced Adam to a slow death and great suffering. Clearly. Please point to a verse that reads *"forcing self-development "*?

Comment: I understand your excitement from R' Hirsh but you need to understand his intentions, he wasn't interpreting the Torah "objectively" he tried his best to fit Torah interpretations into contemporary science and social values so Judaism would not seem so prehistoric. Nothing (practically) in his explanations is Pshat in the Torah.

Comment: Yes, I am giving an interpretation. I believe that is the only way to learn practical lessons from the Torah. Basically, we need to "translate" the stories into our reality. There are clearly no direct instructions on child-rearing in the Torah, so all we have is such interpretations. Actually, if you take the examples you gave and try to "act as God does" without any interpretative appliaction you will badly harm your children, because you will have no tools to "translate" God's actions into educational discipline.

Comment: I completely disagree with what you write about R' Hirsch. You are correct that it is not pshat, but that is by definition. He is giving an interpretation, not translating the words. I believe that he was trying to present universal ideas from the Torah which he believed (and I mostly accept) to be legitimate, true, and eternal lessons, though obviously informed by the ideas of his day.

Comment: You fall into the confirmation bias (I talk a lot about). You pick an opinion and then seek for confirmational interpretations in the Torah. You chose to believe in G-d's benevolence first and then seek compatible interpreters when there's no such Pshat in the open text

Comment: maybe its confirmation bias, or maybe I am trying to learn and these area ideas I learned and accepted. How would you tell them apart?

Comment: Because your acceptance is not based on the objective truth of those ideas but on your personal preferences - whatever you like becomes truthful for you and ideas that you reject become false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96644/discussion-between-simyou-and-al-berko).